# Is it bad practice to doStuff and return a boolean?

Tags: java, null, hashmap, boolean, return

In the java course I'm following right now, I'm required to add a value to the key if the key didn't have a value yet, besides that they also want the method to return true if the key has been added or false when the key already had a value.

```
HashMap<RegistrationPlate, String> register = new HashMap<RegistrationPlate, String>();
public boolean add(RegistrationPlate plate, String owner) {

    if (register.get(plate) == null) {
        register.put(plate, owner);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think it's weird to have an 'add' method which returns truth values, should this have been a void method?

Comment: Not at all weird! This is common practice for making sure your method ran successfully. This way, you can do something like `result = add(x,x)`, and check `result` before continuing. If you worked on the assumption that it worked, it could break more code later on.

Comment: I think it's very bad habit to use `void` in any way. `void` means nothing, it doesn't contribute. returning something is good, since it provides information for free. when you try to return a `void`, think about it what kind of info you can provide in the return value.

Comment: totally fine .for example java `createFile()` return `true` if successfully created else return `false`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it isn't bad to use `void` there are many situations where you would use `void`...

Comment: @brso05 well, you are not forced to return something in all situations. but most of the time, you indeed can return something that helps. in this case, yes. another common example is setter method. why setter should return `void`? it should return, say, the instance itself such that `instance.setF1(f1).setF2(f2).setF3(f3)` is allowed and more concise. many other examples are out there.

Answer (score 2):

In Java's util classes, those methods are widely used.

Just see the class ArrayList, which nearly everybody knows:

In this class there is a method called `boolean add(T e)`, 
and there are many other classes in java who work like that.

In my opinion, it is ok and it makes testing more easy. 
(you can check if the method was successful by the return value)

Answer (score 0):

Returning a boolean for such a thing as adding can be quite useful. In fact `put` returns the old value, as that has its uses.

So you do not need to use `get` - or better `containsKey` but can do:

```
public boolean add(RegistrationPlate plate, String owner) {
    String oldValue = register.put(plate, owner);
    return oldValue == null || !owner.equals(oldValue);
}
```

The `|| ...` is a bit overdone.

Answer (score 0):

> *I think it's weird to have an 'add' method which returns truth values, should this have been a void method?*

Definitely **not** weird. Don't think of `boolean` methods as a way to ask a question and return a yes or no answer. They can do much more!

Take a look at the Java source code and you'll realise how nice it is for certain methods to be of `boolean` return type.
Want to add something to an Object? Was it successful? There are multiple circumstances where `boolean` return types are advantageous for classes/objects/methods communicating between each other.

Take a look at Java's [ArrayList remove(Object) implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) for a great example of `boolean` return types providing extra information.